# how can i delete the previous _id of a user from elastic search?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am doing a project in node.js, MongoDB, and elastic search I am using npm  mongoosastic as for elastic search query. I have a userModel in which the fields name and email indexed. I have added a user in MongoDB user collections and its name and email get indexed but after few days due to some problem I had dropped the user collections and again I had added that user with same emailId and name but now when I am running the same elastic search query on the user collections it is showing me the name but with the previous _id of MongoDB document that I have already deleted. Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how can I fix this issue??

Comment: You need to show some examples of what you are trying to do and what is not working. How is your data? How are you adding it to elasticserch? How are you querying it?

Comment: @leandrojmp sir, my model usermodel is

Comment: @leandrojmp
my elastic search query is
I am using the elastic search query as
 userModel.User.search({
      "multi_match": {
        "fields": ["name", "emails.emailId"],
        "query": name,
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else if (result) {
     console.log(result);
})
where the result shows the output of this query.

Comment: @leandrojmp my user schema is const userSchema = new Schema({
    emails: [{
        emailId: { type: String, es_index: true },
        isPrimary: { type: Boolean }
    }],
    password: { type: String },
    name: { type: String, es_index: true },
    dateOfJoining: { type: Date }})